# Is it possible to easily translate vim search and replace + macros into sed?

Tags: vim, sed

I am using VIM to clean up a data source, and format it properly for use with SIMILE Timeline.

VIM works great, but as far as I know it can't be automated, so I was thinking of using something like SED to clean up the datasource.  I know SED can be used to do search and replace, but when I use VIM to clean the data up, I use a combination of VIM macros and vim regex search and replace.

Is there any equivalent to VIM macros in SED?

Comment: Is it possible to give 1-2 example use cases?

Comment: If you really want, you *can* script vim - see `:help -c`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For very simple text processing (i.e. using Vim like an enhanced 'sed' or 'awk', maybe just benefitting from the enhanced regular expressions in a `:substitute` command), use *Ex-mode*.

```
REM Windows
call vim -N -u NONE -n -es -S "commands.ex" "filespec"
```

Note: silent batch mode `-s-ex` messes up the Windows console, so you may have
to do a `cls` to clean up after the Vim run.

```
# Unix
vim -T dumb --noplugin -n -es -S "commands.ex" "filespec"
```

Attention: Vim will hang waiting for input if the "commands.ex" file doesn't
exist; better check beforehand for its existence! Alternatively, Vim can read
the commands from stdin. You can also fill a new buffer with text read from
stdin, and read commands from stderr if you use the - argument.

For more advanced processing involving multiple windows, and real automation
of Vim (where you might interact with the user or leave Vim running to let the
user take over), use:

```
vim -N -u NONE -n -c "set nomore" -S "commands.vim" "filespec"
```

Here's a summary of the used arguments:

```
-T dumb           Avoids errors in case the terminal detection goes wrong.
-N -u NONE        Do not load vimrc and plugins, alternatively:
--noplugin        Do not load plugins.
-n                No swapfile.
-es               Ex mode + silent batch mode -s-ex
                  Attention: Must be given in that order!
-S ...            Source script.
-c 'set nomore'   Suppress the more-prompt when the screen is filled
                  with messages or output to avoid blocking.
```

Answer (score 3):

Actually, you *can* automate vim, and all the previous versions of vi. (But yes, usually you would use sed(1).) Vim can be started using the ex(1) link, in which case it stays in line mode.

For example:

```
ex - /etc/hosts << \eof
$a
10.11.12.13 a-host-name
.
w /tmp/otherhosts
q
eof
```

If you put that in `autovim.sh` you could just:

```
$ sh autovim.sh
$ cat /tmp/otherhosts
```

Comment: What is ex?  I'm not familar with that.

Comment: When vim is installed a link to it called ex is also installed. When vim starts, it checks to see whether it was run with vim or with ex. If vim, it starts in curses (screen) mode ... what vim calls *visual* mode, but if started via ex, it will start in line mode. Either way, you can switch. Type `Q` in visual mode or `vi` in line mode, and you will find yourself in the other mode.